# handle post request with formdata without express in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, formidable

I want to handle a POST request on the nodeJs server side without using a framework like ExpressJS. The post request works fine from the client end but am not able to get the file or the fields that are included in the POST request. Below is both the client side and the server side code used.

Client Side Code in Angular 7.1.4

```
filelist: FileList 
file: File

sendFile(){
console.log("Send called")
let formdata: FormData = new FormData();
formdata.append('uploadedFile',this.file,this.file.name)
formdata.append('test',"test")
console.log(formdata)
let options = {
  headers:new HttpHeaders({
    'Accept':'application/json',
    'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data'
  })
}
this._http.post('http://localhost:3000/saveFile',formdata,options)
          .pipe(map((res:Response) => res),
                catchError(err => err)
                ).subscribe(data => {
                  console.log("Data is " + data)
                })
}
```

My HTML code

```
<mat-accordion>
<mat-expansion-panel [expanded]='true' [disabled]='true'>
<mat-expansion-panel-header>
  <mat-panel-title>
    Upload File
  </mat-panel-title>
</mat-expansion-panel-header>

<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput placeholder="Work Id">
</mat-form-field>

  <input type="file" (change)="fileChange($event)" >
  <button mat-raised-button color="primary" 
  (click)="sendFile()">Upload</button>

  </mat-expansion-panel>

  </mat-accordion>
```

Server side code in NodeJS v10.13.0

```
//Get the payload
let decoder = new StringDecoder('utf-8')
let buffer = ''


//Listen to request object on data event
req.on('data',(reqData) => {
    console.log("Request Data " + reqData)
    //perform action on the request object
    buffer += decoder.write(reqData)
})

//Listen to request object on end event
req.on('end',() => {

    buffer += decoder.end();

    let form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.parse(req,(err,fields,files) => {

        console.log(fields)
    })
```

I am using `formidable` but am not getting the fields or the files that i append in the `formData` object. 
Below is the output that i get

```
Request Data ------WebKitFormBoundary2SOlG50JexpNBclX
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="uploadedFile"; filename="test.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

//File content
test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test
test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test;test
------WebKitFormBoundary2SOlG50JexpNBclX
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="test"

test
------WebKitFormBoundary2SOlG50JexpNBclX--
```

Answer (score -1):

> ```
>    'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data'
> ```

A multipart/form-data MIME type requires the `boundary` attribute.

Normally, XMLHttpRequest will generate this automatically from the `FormData` object, but Angular overrides the Content-Type by default and then you are overriding it again.

Consequently, Formidable doesn't know where the boundaries are and can't process the request.

You need to stop Angular from overriding it:

```
  headers:new HttpHeaders({
    'Accept':'application/json',
    'Content-Type': null
  })
```